# Defining groups in first order logic without function symbols

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am trying to get used to Prolog, a logic programming language in which I have to enter statements as positive universal Horn sentences and state queries as existential sentences. Let's consider an example.

I want to model groups. I'd chose the symbols $S=\{e, \circ, ^{-1}\}$, where $e$ is a constant, $\circ$ a binary and $^{-1}$ an unary function, and the following axiom set $\Phi_\text{Grp}$ over $S$:

- $\forall u\forall v\forall w. (u\circ v)\circ w=u\circ(v\circ w)$.
- $\forall u. e\circ v=v\circ e=v$.
- $\forall u. u\circ u^{-1} = e$.

These are clearly universal positive Horn sentences.

**Difficulties.** In Prolog, there is yet another restriction: there are no function symbols, but only relations. I could introduce a ternary relation $C$ for composition and a binary relation $I$ for inverse with

- $\forall u\forall v\exists c. C(u,v,c)$, read: every two elements have a composite,
- $\forall u,v,w,c,\dotsc,c'''. C(u,v,c)\wedge C(c, w,c') \wedge C(v,w,c'') \wedge C(u, c''') \to c' = c'''$, which models associativity,

and so on. However, the first one is no universal Horn sentence.

**Question.** I guess FOL with and without function symbols are equivalent (otherwise, I'd bet that one would have included these in Prolog); so how can I define groups in that particular setup?

**Edit.** I just noticed that I can jump from the latter to the former by passing to Skolem normal form (which introduces function, alas). So to rephrase: Is it possible to bring the (any) problem in an equivalent function-free Skolem normal form?

Comment: $∀u∀v∀z∀w [(C(u,v,z) \land C(u,v,w) ) \to z=w]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That only does half of the job, doesn't it? You are stating that composites are unique, provided that they exist.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA No; a positive universal Horn sentence is  a conjunction of sentences of the form $\forall y_1\cdots\forall y_n. \phi$, where $\phi$ is free of quantifiers. Usually, $\phi$ is written down in CNF. In general, for some formula $\psi$, there is a satisfiability-equivalent formula of this form (called the Skolem normal form), but it introduces new function symbols.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Probably I don't understand your question. I haven't defined what a Horn sentence is (otherwise, I'd call them Bubaya sentences); the absence of formulas in logic programming languages is a matter of fact, and expressing the theory of groups seems like a natural example to me.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Not really. The question you refer to is about non-existence and thus can be rewritten as a universal sentence. But I need to assert existence of something.

Comment: Does my answer to your later question answer this one as well? If so, this question should probably be closed as a "duplicate".

Comment: In first-order logic, to assert existence of something, you either need existential quantifiers or function symbols. You can remove existential quantifiers by adding Skolem functions, but then you have function symbols. And you can remove function symbols by replacing them with relation symbols defining the graphs, but then you need existential quantifiers to assert that these relation symbols actually define the graphs of functions. So there's a trade-off.

Comment: I'm confused though - you say "In Prolog... there are no function symbols, but only relations." I don't know much about the Prolog language, but [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog_syntax_and_semantics), it says "A compound term is composed of an atom called a "functor" and a number of "arguments", which are again terms." That sounds like function symbols to me!

Comment: @AlexKruckman According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824709/9484595 and several other sources that come up if one googles "Prolog functions" gives that, apart from some basic  arithmetic functions, every other function $y=f(x_1,\dotsc)$ has to be written as a predicate $F(x_1,\dotsc,y)$.