# Satisfiability equivalent formula without functions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is motivated by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564204/defining-groups-in-first-order-logic-without-function-symbols?noredirect=1#comment7330962_3564204), though more general.

Let $\phi$ be a formula in first order logic (w/o equality) over alphabet $S$ that contains no function symbols. Say $\phi$ is in prenex normal form $\phi = \forall x_1\cdots\forall x_n\exists y_1\cdots\exists y_m.\phi'$, where $\phi'$ is quantifier-free.

*Question.* Is there a formula $\psi$ that is satisfiable iff $\phi$ is, such that

- $\psi = \forall z_1\cdots\forall z_l. \psi'$ with $\psi'$ quantifier-free, and
- $\psi$ contains no function symbols.

I know that with only the first condition, $\psi$ is the Skolem normal form of $\phi$, but Skolemization comes at the cost of introducing new functions.

*Edit:* Of course, I don't know whether $\phi$ is satisfiable or not. Probably, I want to use $\psi$ to decide $\phi$'s satisfiability.

Comment: I think I can give a better answer to your question now. Before I do, a quick question: When you say "formula", do you really mean "sentence" (formula with no free variables)? Or do you allow $\phi$ and $\psi$ to have free variables, in which case "$\phi$ is satisfiable" means "there exists a structure and an interpretation of the free variables as elements of the structure such that $\phi$ is true"?

Answer (score 1):

*Terminology:* A formula like $\phi$ is called a $\forall\exists$-formula (or sometimes an inductive formula). A formula like $\psi$ is called a $\forall$-formula (or a universal formula) with no function symbols.

The question you have asked is not the one you meant to ask.

> "Is there a $\forall$-formula $\psi$ with no function symbols that is satisfiable iff $\phi$ is?"

The answer is yes: If $\phi$ is satisfiable, let $\psi$ be $\forall x\,(x = x)$, which is satisfiable. If $\phi$ is not satisfiable, let $\psi$ be $\forall x\, \lnot (x= x)$, which is not satisfiable.

I suspect what you really want is an *equivalent* formula. That is, you want to pick $\psi$ so that for every model $M$, we have that  $\phi$ is true in $M$ if and only if $\psi$ is true in $M$ (and if $\phi$ and $\psi$ have free variables, we should say that for every model $M$ and every tuple $a$ from $M$ of the appropriate length, $M\models \phi(a)$ if and only if $M\models \psi(a)$).

The answer to this question is no. It's a basic fact of model theory that the truth of $\forall$-formulas is preserved under substructure. So if $\psi$ is a $\forall$-sentence, $M\models \psi$ is a model, and $N$ is a substructure of $M$, then $N\models \psi$ (if this isn't clear to you, you should try to prove it - it's not hard). And if there are no function symbols in the language, then any subset of $M$ is the domain of a substructure.

Now for a counterexample, we can take $\varphi$ to be the $\forall\exists$-sentence $\forall x\, \exists y\, \lnot (x = y)$. Suppose for contradiction that $\varphi$ is equivalent to a $\forall$-sentence $\psi$ with no function symbols. Let $M = \{a,b\}$ be a set of size $2$. Then $M\models \varphi$, so $M\models \psi$. Let $N = \{a\}$ be a substructure of $M$ of size $1$. Since $\psi$ is universal, $N\models \psi$, but also we can see that $N\not\models \varphi$, contradicting equivalence of $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

Your question was originally motivated by trying to express the group axioms by $\forall$-sentences without function symbols. The same argument shows that this is impossible: If the group axioms were expressible by $\forall$-sentences without function symbols, then every subset of a group $G$ would be a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I didn't mean equivalence (I know that that is too strong) but equisatisfiability indeed. Of course, it is a bit cheated if one comes up with a formula depending on the satisfiability of $\phi$. In fact, I want a formula $\psi$ equisatisfiable to $\phi$ *because* satisfiability of $\phi$ might be hard to determine.

Comment: …but your last paragraph seems valuable nevertheless. I need to think about what this means for my problem.